# Pyspark add new column of period starting year and handle leap years

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a data frame and I am trying to add a column with the `target_date`'s period starting date. But I am getting null due to the leap year starting date. Appreciate your help here.

```
+-----+----------+----------+------------+-------+-----------------------+
|   id|start_date|  end_date|target_date_|period_|target_date_fiscal_year|
+-----+----------+----------+------------+-------+-----------------------+
|34667|2017-12-30|2022-12-30|  2021-11-30|      5|                   2020|
|47353|2020-02-10|2023-02-10|  2021-11-30|      3|                   2021|
|94773|2017-04-15|2022-04-15|  2021-11-30|      5|                   2021|
|67324|2017-11-25|2022-11-25|  2021-11-30|      5|                   2021|
|45688|2020-02-29|2025-02-28|  2021-11-30|      5|                   2021|
+-----+----------+----------+------------+-------+-----------------------+
```

**Expected output:**

```
+-----+----------+----------+------------+-------+-----------------------+--------------------+
|   id|start_date|  end_date|target_date_|period_|target_date_fiscal_year|period_starting_date| 
+-----+----------+----------+------------+-------+-----------------------+--------------------+
|34667|2017-12-30|2022-12-30|  2021-11-30|      5|                   2020|          2020-12-30|
|47353|2020-02-10|2023-02-10|  2021-11-30|      3|                   2021|          2021-02-10|
|94773|2017-04-15|2022-04-15|  2021-11-30|      5|                   2021|          2021-04-15|
|67324|2017-11-25|2022-11-25|  2021-11-30|      5|                   2021|          2021-11-25|
|45688|2020-02-29|2025-02-28|  2021-11-30|      5|                   2021|          2021-02-28|
+-----+----------+----------+------------+-------+-----------------------+--------------------+
```

I tried the below code and did not get the correct output.

```
df.withColumn("period_starting_date", F.concat(F.col('target_date_fiscal_year'),
 F.substring(F.col("start_date"), -6, 6)).cast('date')).show()
```

```
+-----+----------+----------+------------+-------+-----------------------+--------------------+
|   id|start_date|  end_date|target_date_|period_|target_date_fiscal_year|period_starting_date| 
+-----+----------+----------+------------+-------+-----------------------+--------------------+
|34667|2017-12-30|2022-12-30|  2021-11-30|      5|                   2020|          2020-12-30|
|47353|2020-02-10|2023-02-10|  2021-11-30|      3|                   2021|          2021-02-10|
|94773|2017-04-15|2022-04-15|  2021-11-30|      5|                   2021|          2021-04-15|
|67324|2017-11-25|2022-11-25|  2021-11-30|      5|                   2021|          2021-11-25|
|45688|2020-02-29|2025-02-28|  2021-11-30|      5|                   2021|                null|
+-----+----------+----------+------------+-------+-----------------------+--------------------+
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are trying to move `start_date` year to `target_date_fiscal_year`?

Comment: yes. I am trying to add starting date of the period of target_date belongs fiscal year as shown in the expected output period_starting_date column

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your code? You can do this with exporting to dictionary

Comment: Sorry. I have added the expected output and what I tried. I am expecting '2021-02-28' instead of 'null in 5th row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can calculate the difference between `target_date_fiscal_year` and year of `start_date`, then add the result to `start_date` to get the `period_starting_date`:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df1 = df.withColumn(
    "period_starting_date",
    F.to_date("start_date") + F.format_string(
        "interval %s year", F.col("target_date_fiscal_year") - F.year("start_date")
    ).cast("interval")
)

df1.show()

#+-----+----------+----------+------------+-------+-----------------------+--------------------+
#|   id|start_date|  end_date|target_date_|period_|target_date_fiscal_year|period_starting_date|
#+-----+----------+----------+------------+-------+-----------------------+--------------------+
#|34667|2017-12-30|2022-12-30|  2021-11-30|      5|                   2020|          2020-12-30|
#|47353|2020-02-10|2023-02-10|  2021-11-30|      3|                   2021|          2021-02-10|
#|94773|2017-04-15|2022-04-15|  2021-11-30|      5|                   2021|          2021-04-15|
#|67324|2017-11-25|2022-11-25|  2021-11-30|      5|                   2021|          2021-11-25|
#|45688|2020-02-29|2025-02-28|  2021-11-30|      5|                   2021|          2021-02-28|
#+-----+----------+----------+------------+-------+-----------------------+--------------------+
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It's working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

In Python there's a beautiful package called `dateutil`, which can help you with your issue.

**NOTE:** You did not add the code, hence, can't check if this is 100% correct.

```py
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

def delta_creator(df):
    delta = df['target_date_fiscal_year'] - df['start_date'].dt.year 
    df['period_starting_date'] = df['start_date'] + relativedelta(years=delta)
    return df
    
df = df.apply(delta_creator, axis=1)
```

Comment: The OP is asking for Pyspark solution not pandas.